# The method getText() is undefined for the type string or mismacth cannot convert from void to string

Tags: android

I have

```
pesan.setText(_cipher.Encrypt(pesan.getText().toString()));
```

when i change to

```
String pesan = text.setText(_cipher.Encrypt(text.getText().toString()));
```

It become type of mismatch cannot convert from void to string. Please someone help me resolve this problem...

Comment: What is text? Edittext??

Comment: Second thing text.setText is void method is will not return any thing it will set Text to Edittext,Textview

Comment: text.setText return type is void you cant assign it to String variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help you:

```
String pesan =_cipher.Encrypt(text.getText().toString());
text.setText(""+pesan);
String pesan1=(text.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @DaniMhsl You need to accept if its workng. just click on right button so answer will be accept

Answer (score 0):

First understand about the return types.

Return type of `setText` is **void**, so you cant assign it to a String.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

Otherwise you can do like this:

```
text.setText(_cipher.Encrypt(text.getText().toString()));
String pesan = text.getText().toString();
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: it still didn't works just got
java.lang.NullPointerException